# RxJava: Convert stream of individual items to a list

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android, rx-java2

I'm trying to figure out how to take a response that returns a list of items, then make a request on each of those items which will return an object and then combine all the responses into a list.

I've got it working by emitting them one at a time, but I would like to package them all back into a list.

I have this so far

```
getListOfData()
.flatMapIterable(list -> list)
.flatMap(item -> getData(item)
```

I've tried toList() but I understand this needs a complete signal before it will ever return anything.

I'm using rxjava 2, I feel like I did this in rxjava 1 with toList() and it worked as expected. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Well, unless you want to return a `List` that contains holes for the items that haven't been returned yet, `toList` is the way to go. And you will get the list when all elements have received their data - `onComplete` doesn't propagate until after the list is propagated.

Comment: That is how I want it to behave, but I don't get anything, `onComplete` never seems to happen, but if I make them individual I can see I get x responses from the first call and then x items being emitted

Comment: Item being emitted is not the same as onComplete, are your sure each individual Observable emit onComplete event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mystery solved.

My original example works with toList()

The issue was I wasn't calling `onComplete` on my `PublishSubject` I was just doing `onNext` maybe I shouldn't be using `PublishSubject` if I don't want to emit multiple things?

Comment: You could probably simplify your code a lot if you *don't* use PublishSubject - there's probably a better way via existing operators.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `fromIterable` instead of `flatMapIterable`, then `toList()` should work

Comment: Could you give an example of this? I can't quite see how to make this work

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?

```
getListOfData()
.flatMapIterable(list -> list)
.flatMap(item -> getData(item))
.flatMap(itemList -> Observable.from(itemList)) // <-- magic here. Maps each result List<Something> to Observable<Something>
```